# Host Angular app in CloudFront/S3 *without* S3 static website hosting

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I'm building an Angular app using AWS CDK. It's for my job, and InfoSec frown on publicly accessible S3 buckets. I'd like to use the new [Distribution API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudfront-readme.html#distribution-api) without configuring the S3 bucket for website hosting. In that case, "the bucket is handled as a bucket origin and CloudFront's redirect and error handling will be used". When I set up the distribution using the following code, the root of the application works (i.e. `/index.html`) but the authentication redirect (`/login/callback`) produces an "Access Denied" XML response. How do I tell CloudFront to redirect *everything* to `index.html`?

```
    const bucket = new Bucket(this, "WebUIBucket", {
      versioned: false,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      autoDeleteObjects: true,
    })

     new BucketDeployment(this, "DeployWebUI", {
      sources: [Source.asset(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../frontend/dist/myapp"))],
      destinationBucket: bucket,
    })

    const cloudFront = new Distribution(this, "CloudFront", {
      defaultBehavior: {
        origin: new S3Origin(bucket),
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      },
      domainNames: [this.frontendFQDN],
      certificate: this.certificate,
      priceClass: PriceClass.PRICE_CLASS_100,
      defaultRootObject: "index.html",
    }

    const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'Zone', { domainName: 'my.tld' })

    new ARecord(this, "frontendDNS", {
      zone: this.zone,
      recordName: 'my-angular-app',
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new CloudFrontTarget(cloudFront)),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted. Thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318922/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-page-via-the-full-url-on-my-website) I found I had to update my CloudFront distribution to the following:

```
    const cloudFront = new Distribution(this, "CloudFront", {
      defaultBehavior: {
        origin: new S3Origin(bucket),
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      },
      domainNames: [this.frontendFQDN],
      certificate: this.certificate,
      priceClass: PriceClass.PRICE_CLASS_100,
      defaultRootObject: "index.html",
      errorResponses: [
        {
          httpStatus: 404,
          responseHttpStatus: 200,
          responsePagePath: "/index.html",
        },
        {
          httpStatus: 403,
          responseHttpStatus: 200,
          responsePagePath: "/index.html",
        },
        {
          httpStatus: 400,
          responseHttpStatus: 200,
          responsePagePath: "/index.html",
        },
      ],
    }
```

What I'm doing here is redirecting errors 400, 403, and 404 back to Angular via `index.html`.

Comment: I can't until tomorrow. :D