# Access Denied when requesting route after authentication - AWS Cloudfront and AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a S3 bucket of a Vuejs application with the content shown in the link
[s3 bucket content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTwaa.png)

To deliver that content i have a distribution in Cloudfront. To make that distribution secure, i created a OAI to associate into Cloudfront distribution and S3 bucket. ** The distribution origin is the bucket not the bucket domain. So when i request the Cloudfront domain the login page is shown, after click on the login button an OIDC flow is started, and when the Callback router is requested is showed a page with acess denied as the link show [acess denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbCSa.png). To try to get around this problem I created a function in CLoudfront that checks the url and renders the index.html, but that didn't work. How can i fix this? Remembering that I don't have a subdirectories with index.html inside them. I have an index.html that loads the js scripts that are built in the vue process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem registering an Error pages in Cloudfront distribution, in my case a 403 error code, so when 403 is launched the Cloudfront redirects to index.html, and from there vue knows what do. btw i found the solution here [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318922/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-page-via-the-full-url-on-my-website)

Comment: After it redirects to the index.html, it not loading the font and icons. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding a web page redirect rule in your S3 that will serve the index.html file if a logical route (Virtual, belongs to the vue router and not a physical file) is hit so that your CF won't serve 404s. Here is a link that explains more about [S3 redirect rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html).

You can try adding this code on your S3 bucket's redirection rule:

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>domain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: actually is like a 403 code. thanks for your response, i will read about the S3 redirect rules.

Comment: You are welcome Wendel! If the solution works, you can mark this response as the answer so other people who experience the same issue can solve the problem too man!

Comment: okay, if it works i will.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the **Rewrites and redirects** configuration for Single Page App in AWS Amplify Console

1. Go to AWS Amplify
2. Choose your application
3. App Setting => Rewrites and redirects
4. Add a rule:

- Source address: `/<*>`
- Target address: `/<*>`
- Type: `404 (Rewrite)`

[image]

Save. Everything has been set up!